# why does this raise a null object exception

Tags: c#, nullpointerexception

I get a Object reference not set to an instance of an object.:OperatorAssembly:  0 line 157. I don't understand what could trigger this exception

```
LogFile.Info("order="+order.Id);

if (order.Location != null)
{
    LogFile.Info("order=" + order.Location.Address);
}    
else
{
    LogFile.Info("order location is null");
}

LogFile.Info("order=" + order.Location.Latitude);
LogFile.Info("order=" +  order.IsResolved);
LogFile.Info("order user id=" + order.User.Id);
LogFile.Info("order ser name=" + order.User.Name);
LogFile.Info("order ser dest =" + order.Destination.Address);                       

line 157:
result = new OrderDataDriver
{
    OrderId = order.Id,
    Address = order.Location.Address,
    Lat = order.Location.Latitude,
    Lng = order.Location.Longitude,
    DestinationAddress = order.Destination.Address,
    DestinationLat = order.Destination.Latitude,
    DestinationLng = order.Destination.Longitude,
    IsCanceled = order.IsCanceled,
    IsPendingResponse = order.IsPendingResponse,
    IsResolved = order.IsResolved,
    UserId = order.User.Id,
    Message = order.MessageForDriver,
    UserName = order.User.Name,
    // IsAdvanceBooking = order.AdvenceBookingTime != null,
    AdvanceBookingTime = order.AdvenceBookingTime,
    AdvancePrice = order.CalculatedPrice,
    AdvanceDistance = order.CalculatedDistance,
    SecondsToRespond = 30,
    Status=order.DriverStatus
};

[DataContract]
public class OrderDataDriver
{

    [DataMember] public string Address { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Feedback { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public double Lat { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public double Lng { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public bool? IsEligible { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public bool? IsCanceled { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public bool? IsResolved { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public bool? IsPendingResponse { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public bool? AllowsTracking { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]


    public int App { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? PreferedDriver { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsAdvanceBooking { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? AdvanceBookingTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? AdvancePrice { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? AdvanceDistance { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DestinationAddress { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double DestinationLat { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double DestinationLng { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int SecondsToRespond { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did you step through the code and see what it thinks is null? what does your log output show as the values for those fields?

Comment: Are you 100% certain of the line number of the error?  Did you add the logging after the error was discovered (which would change your line numbers?  Are you using the latest build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the complex object initialization to something like this:

```
var result = new OrderDataDriver();
result.blablah = foor.bar;
```

Then you will get a better error message which contains the exact line  number which you tried to access a property of a null object.

Here is a good place to refere to this lovely pattern which makes the life of developers easier
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast

Comment: Agreed, this kind of initialization makes debugging horrible for anything more than a handful of properties. And it's ugly.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and the line causing this is result.SecondsToRespond = 30;. I have no idea why

Comment: It means that If you comment this line, no exception will get thrown?

Comment: no, if I comment it out, I get an exception from   var result2 = new OrderDataDriver(); which is even before that. So in the end I solved it by restarting visual studio. I had no idea such problems could occur. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Any one of these accessors could blow up if the property is null:

```
//If Location is null BOOM!!!
Lat = order.Location.Latitude,
Lng = order.Location.Longitude,

//If Destination is null BOOM!!!
DestinationAddress = order.Destination.Address,
DestinationLat = order.Destination.Latitude,
DestinationLng = order.Destination.Longitude,
```

Comment: Yes, but it should blow up before reaching that line.

Comment: Maybe I don't trust his error message :) The code doesn't exactly compile as is... so I assume it was pasted hodge podge from multiple sources.

Answer (score 0):

Since things that could be `null` have already been logged, they should have been caught earlier.

Unless you have a property getter with side effects.  Those are pure evil, so watch out.  Another possibility is that another thread changed a value.  That's even harder to prove.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an object initializer, like

```
result = new OrderDataDriver { OrderId = order.Id, Address = order.Location.Address, Lat = order.Location.Latitude, Lng = order.Location.Longitude, };
```

don't expect the line number (and column number if you have that) to point out exactly which of the "property assignments" inside the braces `{ }` leads to an exception. After all this is translated to assignments to properties of a temporary (invisible) variable. Only if all goes well, the temporary variable is copied to your `result` value.

I have also experienced this inconvenience with the stack trace involving object initializers.